# Weird Formatting on HTML Button

Tags: html, css, button

I have a very simple html web page on which I display two buttons whose contents are pictures of text. The buttons have a white background and gold outline. However, they now have a black bar that protrudes from the right side of each button.

The only way I have found to be able to move them is running

```html
<button class="button button2" style="vertical-align:middle"><a href=""><img class="chatbutton" src="img/chatbutton.png" />
```

where the vertical-align attribute changed if the bar is on the bottom right corner of the button or in the middle of it. 
My code is:

```css
    .button {
          border-radius: 12px;
          background: white;
          border: 4px solid #FFD500;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 20px;
          margin: auto;
          overflow: hidden;
        }

        .button:hover {
        background: #FFD500;
        outline: medium none;
        }

       .button1 {
       width: 150px;
       height: 75px;
        }

        .outer {
         display: table;
         position: absolute;
         height: 100%;
         width: 100%;
        }

        .middle {
          display: table-cell;
          vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .main {
        background-color: white;
        background: white;
        width: 95%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding-top: 40px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        border: 2px solid #494A4A;
          border-radius: 25px;
        margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
         }

        @media screen and (min-width: 480px){
        .main {
      background-color: white;
      width: 50%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 20px;
      padding-top: 40px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      border: 2px solid #494A4A;
        border-radius: 25px;
      margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        }
        }
```

```html
    <body style="background-color:#494A4A">
      <div class="outer">
        <div class="middle">

       <div class="main">
         <button class="button button1" ><a href=""><img 
         class="filebutton" src="" /></button>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
        </body>
```

Comment: Could you post all of your (relevant) code?

Comment: I just edited my post. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend putting an `a` tag inside a `button` tag and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

```css
img { border-radius: 60px; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); width: 284px; height: 108px; object-fit: none; object-position: 50% 20%; } // object position can be adjusted to fit your liking
```

```html
<body>
<a href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRsuLEXVtGfxNCEOgIKdeIT4ki9LK3JwiGAs0YtuAXJHay8WZhw"></a>
</body>
```

I would actually make the image a button itself, rather then using a button tag. But you can also use the button tag and style it.